# Not getting call to loginViewShowingLoggedInUser from FBLoginView

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using the Facebook SDK for the first time.  I am working with Xcode 5.1 and iOS 7.

I programmatically display FBLoginView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if ( !loginView ) {
       // loginView =[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"]];
        loginView =[[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"basic_info", @"user_location", nil]];
    }
    loginView.delegate = self;

    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame,
                    (self.view.center.x -(loginView.frame.size.width /2)), 5);
    CGPoint vCenter   = CGPointMake( CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame),
                                   CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame) );
    CGPoint lvCenter  = CGPointMake( vCenter.x, vCenter.y+100.0 );
    loginView.center = lvCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];

    [self updateView];
}
```

I have implemented the required override functions:

```
#pragma mark - FBLoginViewDelegate

- (void) loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    NSLog(@"loginViewFetchedUserInfo");

     [self updateView];

}
- (void) loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"loginViewShowingLoggedInUser");

    [self updateView];

}
- (void) loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser");

     [self updateView];
}

- (void)updateView {
    NSLog(@"FB updateView");
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>*FBUser, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"updateView - error");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"updateView - good");
             NSNumber    *owner_id  = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[[FBUser id] longLongValue]];
             if ( FB_user_id == nil ) {
                 FB_user_id = owner_id;
                 NSLog(@"FBUser ID  = %@", FB_user_id);

                 loggedInSession = [FBSession activeSession];
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[FBUser id] forKey:@"eventOwnerID"];
                 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"continue_to_app" sender:self];
             }
         }
     }];
    if ([self checkFacebookSession]) {
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    });
}
```

The FBLoginView button appears with "Log in with Facebook".  I can log in and accept permissions, but the loginViewShowingLoggedInUser override function never gets called.

Someone suggested adding the following:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *) application 
                openURL:(NSURL *)url 
                sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
                annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    NSLog ( @"application openURL");
    NSLog ( @"URL = %@", url);
    NSLog ( @"Application = %@", sourceApplication);
    // Call FBAppCall's ha
    BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
    //[LoginUIViewController updateView];

    return wasHandled;
}
```

This code had no effect and was never executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Am I seriously the only person in the world that's come across this?

Comment: I'm currently having a problem where on an iPhone running 8.3, the app delegate URL scheme is never called.  But on an iPad running 8.1, it is called.  (application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:).   So on an iPhone, FBLoginView never redirects to the FB application.  It immediately authenticates automatically, and reads the FB profile.  So it looks like i need to request auth session explicitly in that case.   On All simulators, however, the openUrl: call is invoked from the AppDelegate....  Not sure why this difference of behavior between devices / OS versions.

Answer (score 3):

1. You are using @"basic_info", for this Facebook shows following error when I tried testing your code!

   ```
   Invalid Scope: basic_info. Use public_profile, user_friends instead
   ```
2. I was interested in knowing where did you add the method:

   ```
   - (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *) application 
                openURL:(NSURL *)url 
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
             annotation:(id)annotation 
   {
       NSLog ( @"application openURL");
       NSLog ( @"URL = %@", url);
       NSLog ( @"Application = %@", sourceApplication);
       // Call FBAppCall's ha
       BOOL wasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
       //[LoginUIViewController updateView];

       return wasHandled;
   }
   ```

It should be in your AppDelegate, which works for me.

Comment: If you get the #1 error, you need to replace the `basic_info` with `public_profile`. Facebook has removed `basic_info` from their API since April 31st 2014.

Answer (score 2):

The read permissions have changed.
Refer this :
[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions
][1]

The Error "invalide scope : basic info use public_profile, user friends instead" clearly states that "basic_info" is invalid and it suggests to make use of "public_profile" or "user_friends" as the new scope.

Change it in the following code:

```
    self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info"];
```

TO

```
    self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile"];
```